# Wine Install Total Failure

Tags: linux, installation, wine, ubuntu-11.10

Okay I compiled Wine1.2.3 from source, with the following flags and such:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep wine
./configure --enable-win64
make
sudo make install
```

Took forever to compile, and it does a bunch of crap (below), but then `wine` is unrecognized command. There is no `~/.wine` directory and nothing in `/usr/bin/`

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user1/Desktop/wine-1.2.3/tools/wmc'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user1/Desktop/wine-1.2.3/tools/wrc'
/usr/bin/install -c  -m 644  wrc.man /usr/local/share/man/man1/wrc.1
/usr/bin/install -c   wrc-installed /usr/local/bin/wrc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user1/Desktop/wine-1.2.3/tools/wrc'
```

Comment: could you put the log on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: We need to see the errors. You are showing us all the stuff that succeeded.

Comment: I just copy pasted from the shell which was itself cut off too

Comment: the error will be on the last few lines. The current posted log is useless. Also any specific reason to compile from source?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: If you type "make > make_wine.out" and "make install > wine-install.out", you'll get a full log including the necessary errors. Posting those two files (the .out's) on pastebin would give us enough information to help you with this.